# splice expected to remove multiple elements, but only removes one

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using splice to remove the last `n` number of elements on an array (denoted by `quizResponseCountToRemove`).

However, in its currently implementation, it only removes 1 element.

Is there any particular reason for this?

My code is as follows;

```
  static removeCourseContentElementQuizResponseCount(
    course: ICourse,
    courseContents: ICourseContent[],
    selectedCourseContentUid: string,
    selectedCourseModule: number,
    quizResponseCountToRemove: number
  ): ICourse {
    courseContents.map((courseContent) => {
      if (courseContent.uid === selectedCourseContentUid) {
        courseContent.quiz.options.splice(-1, quizResponseCountToRemove);
        if (courseContent.quiz.answer > courseContent.quiz.options.length) {
          courseContent.quiz.answer = 1;
        }
      }
    });
    course.modules[selectedCourseModule].content = courseContents;
    return course;
  }
```

**Update**

It seems I have misunderstood how splice works. I want splice to work backwards from the last element. So in an array `['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']`, if  `quizResponseCountToRemove` is 2 then I end up with `['test1', 'test2']`.

Comment: Don't use `map` when you're not using the array it creates. Use `forEach` or [any of your other options for looping arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass `splice` a negative number for the first argument, that's an offset from the **end** of the array at which to perform the splice action. You're passing `-1`, so it'll perform its action on the **last** entry in the array. By definition, there's only one last entry in the array, so it doesn't matter how large `quizResponseCountToRemove` is. If it's **any** number over `0`, only one element (the last one) will be removed.

In a comment you've said:

> I want splice to work backwards from the last element. So in an array `['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']`, if `quizResponseCountToRemove` is `2` then I end up with `['test1', 'test2']`

In that case, you want to start `quizResponseCountToRemove` from the end, so you *could* pass in `-quizResponseCountToRemove`:

```
courseContent.quiz.options.splice(-quizResponseCountToRemove, quizResponseCountToRemove);
```

...but that's unnecessarily complicated. To truncate an array, you can just assign to its `length`:

```
courseContent.quiz.options.length -= quizResponseCountToRemove;
```

If it's possible that `quizResponseCountToRemove` might be larger than the array's length, you'll need to ensure you don't try to assign a negative number to `length` (which will cause an error):

```
courseContent.quiz.options.length = Math.max(0, courseContent.quiz.options.length - quizResponseCountToRemove);
```

Live Example:

```js
const courseContent = {
    quiz: {
        options: ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"],
    },
};
const quizResponseCountToRemove = 2;
console.log("before", JSON.stringify(courseContent.quiz.options));
courseContent.quiz.options.length -= quizResponseCountToRemove;
console.log("after", JSON.stringify(courseContent.quiz.options));
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. It seems I misunderstood how splice works. I want splice to work backwards from the last element. So in an array `['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']`, if  `quizResponseCountToRemove` is 2 then I end up with `['test1', 'test2']`.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply TJ. Much appreciated! Will mark as correct shortly.

Comment: `splice` doesn't seem to delete multiple items when start index is negative. `console.log(["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"].splice(-1, 2))` This does not delete the last two items. Can you please tell why?

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee - I explained why in the answer above.

Comment: Ya got it! I got a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `slice` if you are looking to truncate an array. The problem with setting `length` of the array is that the `length` should be **non-negative**, so you need to add some checks.

In code snippet below even if `delCount` is `200`, no additional checks are required `slice` will simply return an empty array. But remember `slice` returns a new array.

```js
const arr = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"],
  delCount = 2,
  newArr = arr.slice(0, -delCount);

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ya agreed. Btw I guess you meant `slice` not `splice`.

Comment: :-) I was **literally** about to delete the comment, because using `slice` creates a new array, which can be useful.